# Node-postgres Db query returning Response with rows property undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am somewhat following the suggested project structure found in the docs.
**server/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
require("dotenv").config();
const restController = require("./restController");

app.get('/users', restController.getUsers)

const PORT = 4000;
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

**server/restController.js**

```
const db = require('../db');

const callback = (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    return next('Query Error, getUsers:', error)
  }
  res.send(result.rows[0])
}
const getUsers = (req, res, next) => {
  const sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM dd_users;'
  db.query(sqlQuery, callback)
}

module.exports = {
  getUsers: getUsers
}
```

**pg/index.js**

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const pgClient = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.CONNECTION_STRING,
  ssl: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
});

const query = (text, params, callback) => {
  return pgClient.query(text, params, callback)
}

module.exports = {
  query: query
}
```

I get a response with undefined in it.

```
Result {
  text: 'SELECT * FROM dd_users;',
  values: undefined,
  rows: undefined,
  types: undefined,
  name: undefined,
  binary: undefined,
  stream: undefined,
  portal: '',
  ...
}
```

I have '?ssl=true' at the end of my connection string.
Any idea what is going wrong? Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Comment: That `callback` in the *restController.js* can't work as it has neither `res` nor `next` in scope

Comment: Where exactly in your code do you get that `Result`?

Comment: You're not passing `params` to your `query` function.

Comment: @Bergi 1 Good pint about the callback, I moved that out recently, moved it back in but I am still no better.

Comment: @Bergi 2 In pg/index.js I ```console.log(pgClient.query(text, params, callback))``` before the return statement, I excluded it for brevity sake. I have never been able to console.log() anything from the callback though. That may tell us something.

Comment: 3  Per the docs, you don't need params. https://node-postgres.com/features/queries - read the first code block. Also, I tried a simple example with params as well. Thanks for your look over my question @Bergi

Comment: You can [edit] the code in the question to fix the definition of the `callback`

Comment: Ah, with `console.log(pgClient.query(text, params, callback))` that result is expected. You're logging whatever it returns immediately, but that result will not yet have any rows - the query has not finished executing. You will indeed need to log in the callback. If you never get a callback, try installing an error handler on the `pgClient`, maybe the connection is failing. Also check the logs of your database.

Comment: @Bergi My db is in Heroku cloud free version, don't know about any logs, don't see any options for it.  I tried Pool as well as Client now - no callbacks are ever reached.

Comment: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors. But really without error messages we can hardly help you. Did you try a [`Client` error handler](https://node-postgres.com/api/client#clientonerror-err-error--void--void)?

Comment: As I said, I have the free version (hobby). On the link you sent it says 'Logs are a production-tier feature. They are not available on hobby-tier databases.' I guess I am not going to get anywhere with Heroku then. @Bergi Thanks for trying to help